# Perl check internet connection for 30 seconds if stable, not stable and no internet connection

Tags: automation, perl, ping

I want script in perl that can check if my internet is stable, not stable or no internet connection.

I use [Net::Ping](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-Ping) script but reply is "`You are connected to the internet.`", not checking internet connection in 30 seconds if stable, not stable or no internet connection. Just reply "`You are connected to the internet.`". But the truth my internet connection is unstable. Every 3 seconds connect - disconnect.

This is the script

```
$ping = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
$ping->port_number("80");
if ( $ping->ping( 'www.google.com', '10' ) ) {
    print "You are connected to the internet.\n";
}
else {
    print "You are not connected to the internet.\n";
}
$ping->close();
```

I want to use `wget` as my tester, but I don't know how to script it in perl. My project is written on perl.

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems quite close to working.  Here is what I ended up with after a little tweaking:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::Ping;

my $ping = Net::Ping->new("tcp");
$ping->port_number("80");
if ( $ping->ping( 'www.google.com', '10' ) ) {
    print "You are connected to the internet.\n";
} else {
    print "You are not connected to the internet.\n";
}
$ping->close();
```

Notes:

- icmp ping requires root privs and could be blocked by google or somebody in between someday so stick with tcp ping.  Nobody is going to block that.
- `use strict` and `use warnings` are good Perl habits to be in
- you need to `use` the module